# why output NUL in console shows char a?

Tags: c++, character

Why does this code output the character a in console?

```
char c = '\0';
std::cout<<c<<std::endl;
```

and this code output is 0?

```
std::cout<<(int)c<<std::endl;
```

Comment: I don't know why the first would print `a`; it doesn't on my system. The second prints `0` because you printed the `int` value `0`; what did you expect?

Comment: What text encoding are you using?

Comment: what you expect it to display?, as its value is null, means nothing, why should it display anything on console?

Comment: @WolfLink windows code page 936, similarly GBK.

Comment: @AliKazmi e, you are right, just curiosity

Comment: which compiler are you using, i have tested it in Visual Studio 2012 its working fine, nothing is shown in output.

Comment: @AliKazmi VS2013，i think the reason is the encoding,but i not sure and i can't change the code page that console use.

Comment: Use Unicode Character Set i am using this default option, try using this